# Character encoding problems with English to Russian translation

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I've used Poedit (running on Win7) to generate .mo/.po files to make a Russian version of a web page using PHP gettext. When I display the Russian version of the page, all the characters are shown as black diamonds/squares.

Here is a sample web page demonstrating the problem:

http://cthorn.co.uk/localization/index.php

... and here is the Russian version:

http://cthorn.co.uk/localization/index.php?locale=ru_RU

The code for `index.php` is:

```
<?php require_once("locale/localization.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p><? echo _("This is the text to be translated."); ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for the file `localization.php` is:

```
<?php
    $locale = "en_GB";
    if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    textdomain("messages");
?>
```

The directory structure is:

```
 - localization
    - locale
       - ru_RU
          - LC_MESSAGES
               messages.mo
               messages.po
         localization.php
      index.php
```

In Poedit I set both "Charset" and "Source code charset" to `UTF-8`. "Language" is set as `Russian` and "Country" is set as `RUSSIAN FEDERATION`.

I made sure that the Russian text was copied from a UTF-8-encoded text file before being pasted into Poedit.

What am I missing?

Here is `messages.po` copied out of Notepad++:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-11-16 10:49-0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2011-11-16 10:49-0000\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: C:\\websites\\cthorn.co.uk\\live\n"
"X-Poedit-Language: Russian\n"
"X-Poedit-Country: RUSSIAN FEDERATION\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: localization/index.php:10
msgid "This is the text to be translated."
msgstr "Это текст для перевода."
```

Ah sorry - download the files from:

cthorn(dot)co(dot)uk/localization/locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
cthorn(dot)co(dot)uk/localization/locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po

(I can only post two links as I'm a n00b)

Comment: I mean the file itself. The text is definitely UTF-8 after you paste it here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure everything is in utf-8 and it will work great.

different Content-encodings always end up as a real pain in the a**

Comment: I thought that I had set everything to UTF-8? I made sure all the PHP files themselves were set to UTF-8 encoding. As you can see in the <head> section the encoding is set as UTF-8, and in Poedit the only character encoding values I could find ('Charset' and 'Source code charset') are set as UTF-8.

Comment: The encoding of your translated text is "ISO-8859-5", try to set `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-5" />` and you will see, so there has to be a problem with your files created by POedit i think. Please make sure the the text you enter in POedit is UTF-8 too.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean now - thank you. I'll try recreating the .mo/.po files now.

Comment: Rebuilding the Poedit files made no difference. I was very careful to copy UTF-8 text from Notepad++ to Poedit, but no joy. Changing the index page's META tag to ISO-8859-5 makes the Russian text work. It seems like Poedit is automatically accepting the text encoded in ISO-8859-5 and not UTF-8. I'll try software other than Poedit and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the russian text on your page is ISO-8859-5. The question is how did it end to be in that encoding :)
Can you show your .po file?

UPD.
Everything in your files looks fine. The only thing I can think of is try this:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.utf8');
    bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work :( All that happens is the page stays English regardless of the ?locale=ru_RU.

Comment: It could mean, that russian language pack is not fully installed on the server. Run `locale -a` in console if you have shell access to the server. It will give you the list of supported locales.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks! I checked to see what languages were installed using `<?php system('locale -a') ?>` and ru_RU.utf8 was listed. Going back to your first suggestion, I used `setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.utf8');` but not `bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');` and hey presto, page works in Cyrillic. Thank you!